# How to find length of a value before the period sign in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the data column like the one mentioned below and I need to find the length of each value starting from left till the period sign (.)

How can I accomplish this in Microsoft SQL Server?

```
abcd.ee (the answer should be 4)
abc.eee (Ans is 3) 
aa.efceg (ans is 2)
```

Comment: `SELECT PATINDEX('%.%' , @var) - 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('.', YourColumn) - 1 AS YourLength
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: It's off by one.  The value needs to be subtracted by 1 to get the length before the period.

Comment: The answer has been updated and now correct (can't delete my prior comment)

Answer (score 1):

It is simply:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('.', @str) - 1
```

`CHARINDEX` gives the position of the `.` within the `VARCHAR` field, hence subtracting by 1 you get the length of the preceding portion.

Numbering in SQL Server string functions starts by 1. This explains the need to subtract by 1 to get the correct result.